# Jira: Can non-administrators import into multiple projects?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

JIRA offers the possibility to import issues specified in a csv file.

From all I know and found, there *should* be a choice to either select the (single) project to import into from a dropdown list, or tick a "defined in csv" checkbox to sepcify multiple projects as a column in the csv.

In our case, it seems only administrators have the "defined in csv" checkbox available. I'm a bit confused, as all information I found either states that **all** importing requires administrator global permission, or does not mention such a requirement at all. I did not find a source that said that all users could import into a single project, and only administrators could import into multiple projects.

Was my research poor? Is there any way to enable standard users to import into multiple projects?

Thanks in advance,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

[JIRA is very flexible when it comes to permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/managing-project-permissions-776636362.html).

You can create custom permission schemes with variation in permission depending on the groups your users are in.

You just need to identify the particular permission associated with imports that you are after. Then, ensure that permission is granted to a particular group (or groups) and that the people you want to be able to import are members of a required group.

Note that you can also assign permissions at the user and role level.

Comment: Thanks, but now I found some other sources stating that CSV import is intended to be a migration tool and not something you use on a daily basis, so that's why it's access is limited to the administrators.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that in JIRA the administrator is just another role. It can be customised like all the other role types. When I worked in a large organisation we had three levels of administrator: the super user that could do everything, department level administrators that could do almost everything and team level administrators that were quite restricted.